# Sending email with java: AuthenticationFailedException: Username and Password not accepted

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

I see the similar questions, but none of them helped me. I am going to send an email using `javaMailSender`. Although, I am sure, I have utilized the valid credential it complains that my username and password is not right. So here is the properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=myemail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= mypassword

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class= javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.fallback= false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

and then making a Bean for injection in the sender class:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("spring.mail.host")
    public SmtpkMailSender getMockMailSender(){
        return new SmtpkMailSender(javaMailSender);
    }

}
```

The sender class only has one method which gets from the below interface:

```
public interface MailSender {
    void sender(String to, String subject,String body);
}
```

Finally, here is the sender:

```
public class SmtpkMailSender implements MailSender   {

    static Log log=LogFactory.getLog(MailSender.class); 

    JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public SmtpkMailSender(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        this.javaMailSender=javaMailSender;
    }

    public void sender(String to, String subject,String body){
        MimeMessage message=javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper=new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(body);
            javaMailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Since i am quit sure about

spring.mail.username=myemail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= mypassword

I went to the link https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps?pageId=none
and set it to the ***on*** but it still complains with the below error:

Here is the error:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials n29sm260426lfi.27 - gsmtp
```

Comment: How are u sure about ur credential. I the problem came from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your email password and try to login with the new password. Also, make sure your username (email address) has the `@gmail.com` at the end. Also, make sure your username and passwords are a String (as denoted by quotes).

Example:

```
spring.mail.username = "myemail@gmail.com"
spring.mail.password= "mypassword"
```

Comment: This is not the perfect solution.Because anyone can send mail from their personal domain rather than using gmail.

Comment: Ik, the author mentioned he used gmail though. Also, if another domain is used then just replace the username with said domain.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem too because the generated password I'm using stopped working. I had to go regenerate new App Password in my google account, which is 16.

[image: new app password generation]

Then place the 16 value as the password and it works.